# How to attach a order pdf copy in email opencart?

Tags: php, opencart2.x

I am new to open cart. I have to attached the PDF contents as well as HTML contents in the email when the user booked their order in open cart 2.x version, so that user will able to download the order PDF.

Comment: Honestly, it's easier just buying an extension, there are many on the OpeCart marketplace

Comment: i don't want to use paid extension.